# How is the Keyboard KeyCode named in Android?

Tags: android, keycode

Does anyone know what is the name of the checkmark blue key code?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's either `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER` or `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE` depending on what listener you use. You need a `OnEditorActionListener` for software keyboards and a `OnKeyListener` for hardware keyboards:

```
val editText = EditText()
editText.setOnKeyListener { _, keyCode, event ->
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
        // do something
        true
    } else {
        false
    }
}
editText.setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
        // do something
        true
    } else {
        false
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks now I found what I need https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/android-ime.md